# PRCE regular expression to exclude a particular character?

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm looking for a regular expression that will match anything that doesn't contain a backslash. I've been trying regexes out on http://regex101.com/#PCRE but neither that not Google is really helping.

I'd like to match any URL string that looks like it has just one slash in the path:

```
/path/page
/path/anypage
```

And not match any URL with more slashes:

```
/path/morepath/page
/path/morepath/andmorepath/page
```

So far, my regex looks like `\/path\/[a-z]+`, but that happily matches the URLs with more slashes in too.

How can I exclude these URLs?

Comment: You forgot to escape your second forward slash and it is acting as an end delimiter: `\/path\/[a-z]+`. Or (depending on the language), you may be able to use a different delimiter like `#` or `~` (`#/path/[a-z]+#`).

Comment: @Sam - thanks, have edited, problem still the same though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a negative lookahead, or with a negated class.

Negated class:

```
^/path/[^/]*$
```

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/eX0rH1)

A negated class will match everything except what's inside, in this case, a forward slash and the anchor `$` at the end ensures that the string is tested till the end.

Negative lookahead:

```
^/path/(?!.*/)
```

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/zT1pJ7)

A negative lookahead will make the whole match fail if what's inside matches. So, if `.*/` matches at the point of the negative lookahead, the match will fail.

Note: I usually use delimiters that uses characters not appearing in my regex. In this case, I change the delimiters from `/` to `~`.

Comment: As a note, depending on the delimiter, the `/`'s may need to be escaped.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I'd figured out the negated class, but didn't realise I had to put the `$` at the end to make sure the whole string was tested. Thanks again for a very helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

this should work :

```
^(?:\/\w+){2}$
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/gM4nG9

Comment: I like this approach.